# Filling arrays with values

Tags: java, arrays

I am 100% sure this already has an answer somewhere, but I've not been able to find it...

I've created an array and specified its length. Later I want to fill it with values, but I can't use the

```
array = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

syntax any more. There's no pattern to the values going in the array, so they can't be put into a for loop where

```
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
     array[i] = someValue[i]
}
```

Can I avoid writing out array[i] = someValue manually for each i? Basically, is there anything similar to

```
array = {1,2,3,4}
```

That I could use, where I just fill the array in one line? If this is incredibly unclear, which it might be, let me know and I'll post the actual code I'm using.

Comment: You can assign to an existing array variable a new array with a list of contents, as `array = new int[] { ... };`. Is that close enough?

Comment: @khelwood That's exactly what I was after. Thanks!

Comment: Also note that since you'll be replacing the value of your `int[]` field/variable anyway, it's redundant to "create an array and specify its length" first; the original array would just get garbage-collected. So simply declare your field/variable as `int[] array;` with no initial value.

Comment: @Jonik Thanks, didn't know that was possible, thought it would result in a compiler error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify, when you do `array = new int[]{1, 2};` as [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250290/filling-arrays-with-values#comment56242178_34250290) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34250294/56285), it creates a *new* array, discarding the array that `array` initially pointed to.

Nothing wrong with that, but note that then it is redundant to first "create an array and specify its length", as you said; the original array just gets garbage-collected. So it makes more sense to simply declare your field/variable as `int[] array;` with no initial value.

On the other hand, if you for some reason specifically want to *reuse* your original array object, filling it with values you come up with later, I think in general you'd have to go with a loop and assigning to `array[i]` "manually".  One exception though: to fill you array (or a part of it), with the *same* value, you can use the built-in [`Arrays.fill()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-int:A-int-) utility. For example:

```
int[] array = new int[5];
Arrays.fill(array, 1);
// array now contains [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]           

// Only fill a specified range:
int[] array2 = new int[10];
Arrays.fill(array2, 3, 7, 2);
// array2 now contains [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Well, I had to declare it at class level to avoid scoping issues. So yes, I used the int[] array declaration without setting an initial value, and it worked very well. Thanks!

Comment: (All that said about arrays, I’d like to add that for most purposes you really should instead use the higher-level, more user-friendly APIs from the [Collections framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html). Supplemented, if you like, by the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) for functional-style operations on Java 8.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this

```
array = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to re-initialize the array using:

```
array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

You cannot use the [Array Initializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) syntax in an assignment, it is only allowed when initializing an array.